# VS 2019 Release build Success, MSBuild Fails

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, class-library

I have a C# class library (4.7 framework) which builds without any errors in visual studio 2019. When I build the same library project using msbuild, it shows errors in the project.

Error codes are: `error CS1002:,  error CS1056, error CS1001`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "TestProject.Common.csproj"
```

Any thoughts or anyone can help me on this.

Comment: You should invoke MSBuild from Visual Studio installation, 12.0 version is too old for VS 2019. Path should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Comment: Are you perhaps building the project in a non-default configuration in Visual Studio? Specify the appropriate `/p:Configuration=...` if so.

Comment: in visual studio I have set /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Comment: @Aruna,any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle this issue, please do not forget to mark it and if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, I'm uninstalling all the previous VS Build Tools and install 2019 VS build tools. I will update you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VS 2019 Release build Success, MSBuild Fails

The issue is quite clear. You just use `MSBuild 12.0` to build a VS2019 net framework 4.7 lib project.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"` is MSBuild of `VS2013` rather than VS2019.

**You cannot use a lower version of MSBuild to build a higher version project.**

**Note**:

`MSBuild 12.0`=>`VS2013` `MSBuild 15.0`=>`VS2017` `MSBuild 16.0/Current`=>`VS2019`

**Suggestion**

So you should use **MSBuild** of **VS2019** to build your project since it builds well in VS2019 IDE.

Use this path to build your project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community or Professional or Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```